Adding elements of of an array of integers
The following code doesn't work as expected.  How can I stop it from concatenating?
function blah(){
let testArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

      console.log('testArray[0]+1 = ' + testArray[0]+1);
      }

https://jsfiddle.net/ut2k67oc/
How to I get this to add an array element to another integer instead of concatenating?

You can use the template literals


function blah() {
  const str = 'testArray[0]+1 = ';
  const testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  console.log(`${str}${testArray[0] + 1}`);
}
blah()




Use parenthesis
function blah(){
  let testArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
  console.log('testArray[0]+1 = ' + (testArray[0]+1));
}


You could also use  testArray[0]+1 = ${testArray[0]+1} 

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Since you add numbers to a string the result is all the operands are concatenated. An easier way is to use multiple console.log arguments, they are evaluated independently and concatenated with a space:


function blah() {
  const str = ' ';
  const testArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  console.log('testArray[0]+1 =', testArray[0] + 1);
}
blah()



